# How to tell if each subsequence is of increasing order python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, sequence, computer-science

Hi :) my question is exactly as the title says. The idea is to make a function that takes a sequence and a desired length for subsequences. Then return how many of those subsequences is in increasing order. I think I got the first part (of splitting the one sequence into x length subsequences) but I have no idea how to tell how many of those are in increasing order so any help would be appreciated. This is what I have so far:

```
def subsequences(sequence, length):
     [sequence[i :i+length] for i in range (0, len(sequence0, length)]
```

This splits the sequence. How do I tell how many subsequences are in increasing order? For example:

```
   >>>subsequences(‘1234’, 2)
```

would first find the subsequences so ‘12’ and ‘34’ and would then check how many of those are in increasing order. Would return 2 since two subsequences are in increasing order.

```
   >>>subsequences(‘12135267’, 2)
```

Would first find the subsequences so ‘12’, ‘13’, ‘52’, ‘67’. Would then see that only three of those are in increasing order. Would return 3

```
   >>>subsequences(‘322123453678’, 3)
```

Would find the subsequences so ‘322’, ‘123’, ‘453’, 678’. Would then see that only two of those are in increasing order. Would return 2

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there some sample (small) inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: I added some examples

Answer (score 1):

The general way in Python to tell if a sequence s is in increasing order is

```
import itertools
all(x <= y for x, y in itertools.pairwise(s))
```

You may need to change `<=` to '<' depending on whether you consider `1223` to be an increasing sequence or not.

You should be able to fit this into your program.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer :). For some reason, I can’t import intertools … it gives me a ModuleNotFoundError saying there is no module named intertools. Can you think of any other way to solve this? If not no worries!

Comment: `itertools`, not `intertools`.